# socket server could not receive the message send by client

Tags: c++, qt

I use Qt creator 5.5.1 in windows 7.

The complier is VC 2010 32Bits.

I have written a socket client. It could connect well but the message could not be sent to the server.

No error occurs when I debug the program.

```
char flash_result_data[] ={'0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'};


void MainWindow::on_pushBtn_LoadCfg_clicked()
{


 if (tcpClient == NULL)                     
 {
    tcpClient = new QTcpSocket;
    tcpClient->connectToHost(ui->txtIPServer->text(),ui->txtPortServer->text().toInt());

    Sleep(1000);
    QObject::connect(tcpClient,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(readMessageFromTCPServer()));
    QTimer::singleShot(100000, this, SLOT(fun_timer()));
  }  
}
void MainWindow::readMessageFromTCPServer()
{
  QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL( MySignal() ),this, SLOT( MySlot() ) );



  std::string r="start";

  QByteArray qba;

  qba= tcpClient->readAll();
  if (qba.contains(r.c_str()))
  {
    emit MySignal();
  }
  return;

}
void MainWindow::fun_timer()
{

  int flash_result_data_size = sizeof(flash_result_data) / sizeof(char);
  std::string  flash_result_data_str = convertToString(flash_result_data, flash_result_data_size);
  tcpClient->write(flash_result_data_str.c_str(),strlen((flash_result_data_str.c_str())));

}
```

When I debug the program, the socket could connect well. And after run this line: `tcpClient->write(flash_result_data_str.c_str(),strlen((flash_result_data_str.c_str())));`  , no error occurs, but there is no message received from socket server.

The socket server is developed by others and is used many times in other similar project so the server must be OK. The problem is my client code. But I do not know where my error is.

Comment: You have to debug the server application to see whats going on there after the possible "read" function. Is it even called after connection or maybe the server is first trying to send something so he doesn't read anything (so it would be the task of the client to read something first e.g.)

Comment: wireshark is often useful in these situations, will tell you whether you are actually sending anything and whether the server is replying. you should then be able to narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: `readMessageFromTCPServer` is unlikely to work though, you wont necessairly receive whole messages in a single packet so need to accumulate bytes until you have a whole message

Comment: @Alan Birtles wireshark will get the packet , and could the server get the packet after using wireshark?

Comment: @Alan Birtles You mean readMessageFromTCPServer could only receive a single packet? How should I change my code then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of the file add `#include<QDebug>`.

In MainWindow class header file, add `QByteArray qba;` as a private member variable.

Change your readMessageFromTCPServer to:

```
void MainWindow::readMessageFromTCPServer()
{
  QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL( MySignal() ),this, SLOT( MySlot() ) );


  std::string r="start";

  qba.append(tcpClient->readAll());
  qDebug() << "BUFFER:" << QString::fromUtf8(qba);

  if (qba.contains(r.c_str()))
  {
    emit MySignal();
  }
  return;

}
```

Look at `qDebug` output to see how the data is being received.
Also, I think this connection is not necessary `QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL( MySignal() ),this, SLOT( MySlot() ) );`.

You could just call `MySlot();` since both the signal and the slot are part of the same object.

```
if (qba.contains(r.c_str()))
  {
    MySlot();
  }
```